# Different URLS for different auth providers, under one web application and site collection

Tags: security, authentication, forms-authentication, web-application, windows-authentication

We have a single site collection setup within a web application. The site collection has one top-level site, and the setup has one content database. The application is using Forms authentication for its customers, along with Windows Authentication for its employees. For customers, the URL should be different from the URL the employees login to. (i.e. employee.userportal.com &  userportal.com).

Currently we have a custom login screen that allows FBA users to enter their username or password. We also have an "Employee Login" link pointing towards the windows auth login prompt for employees. However, the client does not want customers to see the "Employee Login" link.

How can I setup a seperate URL for the login page/authentication, but keep the simple, single web-application/site-collection approach?

*SharePoint 2013 On-premise.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have only one site collection in the web application. So here what i think will be easy solution. You should take advantage of the different Zones of the Web Application.

1. You extend your web application to different zone
2. Now configure default zone with Windows Auhtnetication and URL( update the AAM with URL which employee Access)
3. Now Extended zone you have to configure the FBA authentication and UPdate AAM with that URL.

One thing keep in mind if you move the FBA to different zone then you have to update the Web.config settings as well.

In above scenrio, you have two different url but points to same content.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261698(v=office.14).aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint_strategery/archive/2013/05/27/alternate-access-mappings-explained.aspx